# MATLAB compiled code under mac OS X

Tags: matlab, deployment, compiler-construction

I'm having some issues with a MATLAB compiled code under mac. I've tested the same program under windows and linux aswell with NO issue at all.
My program needs two folders to work properly, but it seems that mac doesn't like them, because it can't see them. On the contrary win and linux have no problem seeing and using that folders.
I just want to underline that I obviously put these folders in the deploytool package before creating the package.

Any idea?
Maybe I'm running the program unproperly setting the environmental variables in an unproper way.

edit:
matlab error just after the program has started.

`Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: materials`

but `materials` folder is in my "current directory" and I did put that in the deploytool folder too, why it can't see that? It seems an `addpath` error, but why it doesn't appear under linux and windows?!

Comment: Tell us more about your problem. What are the absolute paths of the folders?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few things to think about:

1. Have you set your permissions to the folders correctly? I would assume the permissions for OSX should be the same as you used in Linux, but perhaps you forgot to update them after you created the folders?
2. Is Matlab running as the user you think it is? I don't know about Matlab specifically, but its possible it runs as a particular user depending on the environment you are in.
3. Is your error definitely that the folders are not found? Sometimes errors regarding disk IO are vague or misleading (like when due to permissions - see point 1 and 2).

Comment: The strange message that appears is: Warning: application is running on a locale different from the original platform locale. I googled but the post are not related to my problem. I seemed to me also that it's a folder permission. I know that Mac has all these issues about permission and we must know everything about that while we use mac, but matlab usage under os x it's really weird...

Comment: I'm definitely not a Matlab expert, but is there an actual Error after that warning? Does the code stop/crash/hang?

Comment: definetely not, it starts perfectly but but some of its functionalities doesn't work properly!